# PostgreSQL, how to query the database to retrieve the percentile elements of a dataset?

Tags: postgresql, top

I need a PostgreSQL query that do the following job: given a percentage (e.g. 10%), the query should **return each 1st element of each percentile**, among all the elements selected.

So suppose in this simple case my table contains elements which are integer values between 1 and 100:

```
id    | value
--    | -----
id1   | 1
id2   | 2
...
id100 | 100
```

And suppose the input percentile is 10%. 
The query should divide all the dataset into spans whose range is 10%, and return each first element.
So the output should be:

```
id1 | 1
id11 | 11
id21 | 21
id31 | 31
id41 | 41
id51 | 51
id61 | 61
id71 | 71
id81 | 81
id91 | 91
```

Does anyone knows how I could write this Sql query? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize `NTILE` to create *n* quantiles:

```
select id, min(value)
from
 (
   select id, value, 
      ntile(10) over (order by value) as nt
   from tab
 ) as dt
group by id, nt
```